# MySQL generate a sublist of comment in a query

Tags: mysql, sql, json, join

I have a database of 3 tables Question, Answer, Comment it works as it is supposed to, each Question can have multiple Answers and each Answer can have multiple Comments

```
create table Question(
    questionId int primary key auto_increment,
    title varchar(34) not null,
    content TEXT not null
);

create table Answer(
    answerId int primary key auto_increment,
    questionId int not null,
    content TEXT not null
);

create table Comment(
    commentId int primary key auto_increment,
    answerId int,
    questionId int,
    content TEXT not null
);

insert into Question(title, content) values('Testing Question','Testing Question');

insert into Answer(questionId, content) values(1,'Testing Answer 1');
insert into Answer(questionId, content) values(1,'Testing Answer 2');

insert into Comment(answerId, questionId, content) values(1, 1,'Testing Comment 1 to Answer 1');
insert into Comment(answerId, questionId, content) values(1, 1,'Testing Comment 2 to Answer 1');
insert into Comment(answerId, questionId, content) values(2, 1,'Testing Comment 1 to Answer 2');
insert into Comment(answerId, questionId, content) values(2, 1,'Testing Comment 2 to Answer 2');
```

I would like when i query an answer and its comments i get the comments in a List such as:

```
[
{ answerId: 1, answerContent: 'Answer Content', comments[...]},
{ answerId: 2, answerContent: 'Answer Content', comments[...]}
]
```

Is this possible? i have tried to use this query:

```
select * from Answer inner join Comment on Comment.answerId = Answer.answerId where Comment.questionId = 1;
```

And obviously it gives me back this:

```
[
    {
        "answerId" : 1,
        "questionId" : 1,
        "content" : "Testing Answer 1",
        "commentId" : 1,
        "answerId" : 1,
        "questionId" : 1,
        "content" : "Testing Comment 1 to Answer 1"
    },
    {
        "answerId" : 1,
        "questionId" : 1,
        "content" : "Testing Answer 1",
        "commentId" : 2,
        "answerId" : 1,
        "questionId" : 1,
        "content" : "Testing Comment 2 to Answer 1"
    },
    {
        "answerId" : 2,
        "questionId" : 1,
        "content" : "Testing Answer 2",
        "commentId" : 3,
        "answerId" : 2,
        "questionId" : 1,
        "content" : "Testing Comment 1 to Answer 2"
    },
    {
        "answerId" : 2,
        "questionId" : 1,
        "content" : "Testing Answer 2",
        "commentId" : 4,
        "answerId" : 2,
        "questionId" : 1,
        "content" : "Testing Comment 2 to Answer 2"
    }
]
```

I have tried also using the group by in the previous query like this:

```
select * from Answer inner join Comment on Comment.answerId = Answer.answerId where Comment.questionId = 1 group by Comment.questionId;
```

And it gives me back this:

```
[
    {
        "answerId" : 1,
        "questionId" : 1,
        "content" : "Testing Answer 1",
        "commentId" : 1,
        "answerId" : 1,
        "questionId" : 1,
        "content" : "Testing Comment 1 to Answer 1"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json_arrayagg()`:

```
select a.*, json_arrayagg(c.content)
from Answer a inner join
     Comment c
     on c.answerId = a.answerId
where c.questionId = 1
group by a.answerId
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=97f57773e4320c168af64d57cbe3dbbf) is a db<>fiddle.

If you want all rows, even those with no comments, you can use:

```
select a.*, json_arrayagg(c.content)
from Answer a left join
     Comment c
     on c.answerId = a.answerId and
        c.questionId = 1
group by a.answerId
```

Comment: I have tried as you said (i also added a semicolon to the end of the query) but it's not working, anyway thx!

Comment: @AndreaDattero . . . I fixed the typo and added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I have encountered a problem however the answers can also have obviously no comment if this happens when i use your query (or everybody elses) it returns me an empty array cause the comments don't exist for that answer and because of that it doesn't show me the content of the entire row (answer and comment) is there a way to avoid this? i would like that if there is no comment at least it shows me the answer is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I only show answerid and questions1 from answers
The rest is a [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) AND [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat)

> ```
> select a.answerId, a.questionId, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.content) answerContent, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.content) comments
> from Answer a inner join Comment c on c.answerId = a.answerId 
> where c.questionId = 1
> GROUP BY a.answerId;
> ```
>
> ```
> answerId | questionId | answerContent    | comments                                                   
> -------: | ---------: | :--------------- | :----------------------------------------------------------
>        1 |          1 | Testing Answer 1 | Testing Comment 1 to Answer 1,Testing Comment 2 to Answer 1
>        2 |          1 | Testing Answer 2 | Testing Comment 1 to Answer 2,Testing Comment 2 to Answer 2
> ```

> ```
> select a.answerId, a.questionId, a.content answerContent, c.content comments
> from Answer a inner join Comment c on c.answerId = a.answerId 
> where c.questionId = 1
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> answerId | questionId | answerContent    | comments                     
> -------: | ---------: | :--------------- | :----------------------------
>        1 |          1 | Testing Answer 1 | Testing Comment 1 to Answer 1
>        1 |          1 | Testing Answer 1 | Testing Comment 2 to Answer 1
>        2 |          1 | Testing Answer 2 | Testing Comment 1 to Answer 2
>        2 |          1 | Testing Answer 2 | Testing Comment 2 to Answer 2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b4be9f86e34be775c4d3aeac2931c3b5)*

Comment: Ok i +1 your question, it may be a good solution (even though i'd have to split the comments in my js file), have you anyother idea on how this could be done?

Comment: You can remove the GROUP BY  and GROUPm CONCAT and then run in your js over all rows, but that solution you already had as far as i can see, and it is not that complicated , to split them up again and use in a loop, of course you can change the  comma seperated to another character

Comment: Yes i was thinking of looping the json and everytime i find the same answerId i push the comment in a list, when the id changes i push the previous generated list of comments in a list of lists and start putting the next comments inside a new list for the new different answerId, but i thought this wasn't very efficient and i would have liked to have mysql db to do this for me (as it maybe more efficient i guess???)